# Converting ansible jinja2 for loop to a list

Tags: for-loop, ansible, jinja2

I currently have a problem with jinja2 for loop in Ansible. I want to extract the `title` of any windows updates that available with Ansible.

I tried to get back the result with this:

```yaml
- win_updates:
    category_names: "{{ win_update_categories }}"
    state: searched
  register: available_updates

- debug: msg="{{ available_updates }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ item['title'] }}"
  with_items: " {{ available_updates['updates'] }}"
```

And I got this back:

```json
"msg": "available_updates = {'updates': {'74f56410-a048-4c27-91de-5f09600944c7': {'categories': ['Definition Updates', 'Microsoft Defender Antivirus'], 'title': 'Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus antimalware platform - KB4052623 (Version 4.18.2107.4)', 'id': '74f56410-a048-4c27-91de-5f09600944c7', 'installed': False, 'kb': ['4052623']}, '7b31e2cf-c6b0-434e-9420-97c6fe756573': {'categories': ['Security Updates', 'Windows Server 2019'], 'title': '2021-08 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2019 for x64-based Systems (KB5005030)', 'id': '7b31e2cf-c6b0-434e-9420-97c6fe756573', 'installed': False, 'kb': ['5005030']}}, 'found_update_count': 2, 'changed': False, 'reboot_required': False, 'installed_update_count': 0, 'filtered_updates': {}, 'failed': False}"
```

```json
ok: [172.16.1.1] => (item=74f56410-a048-4c27-91de-5f09600944c7) => {
    "msg": "<built-in method title of AnsibleUnsafeText object at 0x7f1f9a4bec80>"
}
ok: [172.16.1.1] => (item=7b31e2cf-c6b0-434e-9420-97c6fe756573) => {
    "msg": "<built-in method title of AnsibleUnsafeText object at 0x7f1f9a4bef90>"
}
```

As you see the `title` is coded or something like that.

So, I did some search and found this solution that uses jinja2 and for loop to get back the title of updates.

```yaml
- win_updates:
    category_names: "{{ win_update_categories }}"
    state: searched
  register: available_updates

- set_fact:
     available_updates_title: >-
       "{% for update in available_updates.updates.values() %}
          {{ update.title }}
        {% endfor %}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ available_updates_title }}"
```

and I got this back:

```json
"msg": "  Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus antimalware platform - KB4052623 (Version 4.18.2107.4)\n  2021-08 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2019 for x64-based Systems (KB5005030)\n"
```

It worked correctly but I want to create a list of titles that available for each server while the `jinja2 for loop` creates a row of titles.

So my question is how can I convert the output of `jinja2` to a list that can iterate over it with Ansible?

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is quite hard to answer precisely without knowing what your `available_updates` variable precisely looks like. You should edit your question do add a debug output of the variable. Meanwhile, If I believe the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_updates_module.html#return-values) and if I correctly understood that you want a list of all updates titles returned by the module => `{{ available_updates.updates | map(attribute='title') }}`

Comment: Hi and thanks for your time. I've added the whole `available_updates` variable. and your solution didn't work.

Comment: I reviewed my question and try to say it in a different way. I think my previous question was totally confusing!

Comment: What is really confusing is that you had put a debug of the full var and removed it again. This is essential for someone to answer your question. Please add it back and formatted correctly.

Comment: It's there. I didn't remove it. The second code is the whole variable. Exactly after *`And I got this back:`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about my comment regarding your data not being there. Meanwhile, a simple and stock debugging of your var without any extra chars, i.e.

```yaml
- debug:
   var: available_updates
```

would have given a much easier readable result and removed possible confustion from start:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "available_updates": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "filtered_updates": {},
        "found_update_count": 2,
        "installed_update_count": 0,
        "reboot_required": false,
        "updates": {
            "74f56410-a048-4c27-91de-5f09600944c7": {
                "categories": [
                    "Definition Updates",
                    "Microsoft Defender Antivirus"
                ],
                "id": "74f56410-a048-4c27-91de-5f09600944c7",
                "installed": false,
                "kb": [
                    "4052623"
                ],
                "title": "Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus antimalware platform - KB4052623 (Version 4.18.2107.4)"
            },
            "7b31e2cf-c6b0-434e-9420-97c6fe756573": {
                "categories": [
                    "Security Updates",
                    "Windows Server 2019"
                ],
                "id": "7b31e2cf-c6b0-434e-9420-97c6fe756573",
                "installed": false,
                "kb": [
                    "5005030"
                ],
                "title": "2021-08 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2019 for x64-based Systems (KB5005030)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now it becomes obvious that `available_updates.updates` is a dict with keys being the `id` of your updates and the corresponding values containeing all the details about each update.

The general oneliner idea to extract the update `title` in very first comment is still good except that we need to transform the dict into a list before applying the map filter to extract the attribute. This can be done either using the `.values()` method on the dict (as already present in your examples) or using the `dict2items` filter. The following playbook demonstrate both possible methods

```yaml
---
- name: Extract list of elements from dict
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # Your orig var on a single line for legigility
    available_updates: {'updates':{'74f56410-a048-4c27-91de-5f09600944c7':{'categories':['Definition Updates','Microsoft Defender Antivirus'],'title':'Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus antimalware platform - KB4052623 (Version 4.18.2107.4)','id':'74f56410-a048-4c27-91de-5f09600944c7','installed':False,'kb':['4052623']},'7b31e2cf-c6b0-434e-9420-97c6fe756573':{'categories':['Security Updates','Windows Server 2019'],'title':'2021-08 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2019 for x64-based Systems (KB5005030)','id':'7b31e2cf-c6b0-434e-9420-97c6fe756573','installed':False,'kb':['5005030']}},'found_update_count':2,'changed':False,'reboot_required':False,'installed_update_count':0,'filtered_updates':{},'failed':False}
    # Equivalent var definitions
    title_list_using_values_method: >-
      {{ available_updates.updates.values() | map(attribute='title') }}
    title_list_using_dict2items_filter: >-
      {{ available_updates.updates | dict2items | map(attribute='value.title') }}

  tasks:
    - name: "Show the original var (use -v to display)"
      debug:
        var: available_updates
        verbosity: 1

    - name: "Show result with both definitions"
      debug:
        var: "title_list_using_{{ flavor }}"
      loop:
        - values_method
        - dict2items_filter
      loop_control:
        loop_var: flavor
```

and gives:

```
PLAY [Extract list of elements from dict] *****************************************************************************

TASK [Show the original var (use -v to display)] *****************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Show result with both definitions] *****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=values_method) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "flavor",
    "flavor": "values_method",
    "title_list_using_values_method": [
        "Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus antimalware platform - KB4052623 (Version 4.18.2107.4)",
        "2021-08 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2019 for x64-based Systems (KB5005030)"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=dict2items_filter) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "flavor",
    "flavor": "dict2items_filter",
    "title_list_using_dict2items_filter": [
        "Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus antimalware platform - KB4052623 (Version 4.18.2107.4)",
        "2021-08 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2019 for x64-based Systems (KB5005030)"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: `@Zeitounator` Thanks for your time and explain as simple as possible the whole situation.

Answer (score 0):

i had a simliar problem and I solved it using something like :

```
available_updates['updates'].categories
```

or

```
available_updates['updates']['categories']
```

Comment: Thanks but my problem is `title` not `categories`